# how to change 2D Eigen::Tensor to Eigen::Matrix

Tags: tensorflow, eigen3

Seems simple enough. I would have thought some kind of casting would be possible, but I can't seem to find any documentation for it.

While I have found ways in my application to avoid using the Eigen::Matrix class, TensorFlow only works with Eigen::Tensor, and another library I use only has functionality for working directly with Eigen::Matrix. It would be spectacular for code readability if I could cast a Tensor as a Matrix and work with that.

<strike>edit: it seems that TensorFlow DOES have a function to get an Eigen::Matrix out (still testing it out). Maybe that makes the original question less interesting (maybe no one NEEDS to convert Tensors to Matrices.) However I still think it's a valid question to ask. so I won't put down my</strike>

edit 2: going through the TF documentation after some build errors, it seems that tensorflow's Tensor::matrix() function simply returns a 2d Eigen::Tensor, so the conversion is in fact necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a common use case for TensorFlow's linear algebra ops, and an implementation can be found in [`tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/91a70cbf1c627117b70a3d2dd4c612779369e293/tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.cc#L208). However, that code is highly templatized, so it might be useful to have a concrete example.

Assuming you start with a `tensorflow::Tensor` called `t` with element type `float`, you can make an Eigen matrix `m` as follows:

```
tensorflow::Tensor t = ...;

auto m = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<
             float,           /* scalar element type */
             Eigen::Dynamic,  /* num_rows is a run-time value */
             Eigen::Dynamic,  /* num_cols is a run-time value */
             Eigen::RowMajor  /* tensorflow::Tensor is always row-major */>>(
                 t.flat<float>().data(),  /* ptr to data */
                 t.dim_size(0),           /* num_rows */
                 t.dim_size(1)            /* num_cols */);
```

If your tensor comes from the input of a `tensorflow::OpKernel` (e.g. in the `Compute()` method), you would use a slightly different type with the appropriate `const` qualification:

```
OpKernelContext* ctx = ...;
const tensorflow::Tensor t = ctx->input(...);

const auto m = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<
                   float,           /* scalar element type */
                   Eigen::Dynamic,  /* num_rows is a run-time value */
                   Eigen::Dynamic,  /* num_cols is a run-time value */
                   Eigen::RowMajor  /* tensorflow::Tensor is always row-major */>>(
                       t.flat<float>().data(),  /* ptr to data */
                       t.dim_size(0),           /* num_rows */
                       t.dim_size(1)            /* num_cols */);
```

Comment: Oh hey, I saw this right as I was finishing my edit. This answer actually makes more sense than I though it would. Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: Yeah, half the battle is unpicking the template definitions :). Glad to help!

Comment: Also, while your answer was entirely correct, the general Tensorflow use case for this would likely involve getting the tensor via an OpKernelContext* input function, which returns a const Tensor. Likewise the Eigen::Matrix being mapped to needs to be const too. (This is just for those folks like me who don't know c++ very well and can't read compiler errors very well. I spent an hour figuring out why it was complaining about not finding a suitable constructor.)

Comment: That's a great point! In that case you probably want to use the `ConstMatrixMap` from [`tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/91a70cbf1c627117b70a3d2dd4c612779369e293/tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.h#L113). Note that it's defined inside a class that is in turn templated on a `Scalar` type (such as `float`). I updated the answer with a concrete type for this.

Comment: @mrry Many, many thanks for your answer! How do we then assign our result of type `Eigen::Matrix` to our output_tensor of type `tensorflow::Tensor` after we have done our calculations?

Comment: Ahhh. We drop constness and do the same thing. Brilliant.

Comment: @mrry is this answer still correct with tf. 1.8? I'm trying to do the same thing but I'm facing a lot of compile time errors

Comment: As far as I know, it is, yes.