# How do I Multiply two matrices in a TensorFlow custom op?

Tags: matrix, tensorflow

I am trying to multiply two matrices with the following code pieced together from examples in `tensorflow/core/kernels`.

```
void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {

    const Tensor& A = context->input(0);
    const Tensor& B = context->input(1);

    const auto A_mat = A.matrix<T>();
    const auto B_mat = B.matrix<T>();

    Tensor* output_tensor = nullptr;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, A_tensor.shape(), &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->matrix<T>();

    output = A_mat * B_mat;
}
```

With

```
A = [[ 25.90848866  23.31998387  38.59424611]
     [ 48.12131663  48.15446712   0.27323556]
     [ 50.99763646  25.77013947  24.67779583]
     [ 14.43187796  20.18683861  45.63747844]
     [ 23.09759944  49.91747332  31.83040427]
     [  3.01687455  15.14876558  41.13147952]
     [ 41.32467959  49.91440187  21.21775212]
     [  5.48660952  39.98743312   3.33354911]]

B = [[    0.999994 1.98149e-05 -0.00337665 ]
     [ 1.98149e-05    0.999931    0.011736 ]
     [  0.00337665   -0.011736    0.999925 ]]
```

I get

```
output = [[  4.04171173e+001   6.19674481e-004  -6.08213832e-002]
          [  6.27670070e-004   5.15969690e+000   4.23702253e-001]
          [  1.18978160e-001  -3.34875362e-001   1.78214391e+001]
          [  0.00000000e+000   1.78005398e-313   2.44005345e-309]
          [  4.62065626e+064   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000]
          [              nan               nan   5.00303243e+065]
          [  3.45845952e-323   2.02072849e-321   2.72281224e-308]
          [  0.00000000e+000   3.28336636e-308   0.00000000e+000]]
```

However, if the op is `output = A_mat + A_mat` (plus instead of matmul) the output is `2*A_mat` as expected. What is going on here? Can we not work with Eigen vectors, matrices and tensors like this in custom ops? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [how to change 2D Eigen::Tensor to Eigen::Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475356/how-to-change-2d-eigentensor-to-eigenmatrix) it turned out to be straightforward to multiply two tensors with Eigen notation.

The issue related to `const auto A_mat = A.matrix<T>();` which returns a `tensorflow::Tensor` and not an `Eigen::Matrix`. This can be achieved with `Eigen::Map` as given below.

```
void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {

    const Tensor& A = context->input(0);
    const Tensor& B = context->input(1);

    const auto A_mat = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>(
        A.flat<T>().data(), A.dim_size(0), A.dim_size(1));

    const auto B_mat = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>(
        B.flat<T>().data(), B.dim_size(0), B.dim_size(1));

    Tensor* output_tensor = nullptr;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, A_tensor.shape(), &output_tensor));

    const auto output = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>(
        output.flat<T>().data(), output.dim_size(0), output.dim_size(1));

    output = A_mat * B_mat;
}
```

(notice that we dropped the constness of the output matrix)

Comment: Following this I get a segfault with CUDA. Obviously Eigen is trying to do the Matrix math on the CPU with GPU addresses. Is there a way to make Eigen or TensorFlow perform this operation on the GPU?

Comment: There most definitely is but I think this functionality warrants its own question. I don't know the answer but would very much like to know.