# Extract matrix from batch, represented as Tensor

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I'm using Tensorflow in C++. I'm using a trained model to extract patches from an input image.

My output tensor (after session Run) is `outputs` and has in `outputs[0]` a batch of N patches, MxMxD.

```
auto patches = outputs[0].tensor<float, 4>();
```

Now, I want to display this images using OpenCV, in particular, I want to use the `cv::eigen2cv` function, that given an `Eigen::Matrix` gives me a `cv::Mat`.

The problem is that I need to loop over this output tensor and for each element, extract an `Eigen::Matrix`.

I've tried the proposed solution, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39475756/2891324 but I can't even compile the code because of Eigen error: EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_ONLY:

```
const auto patch_side = 256;
int batch_id = 0;
using Matrix =
    Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;
for (auto i = 0; i < grid_shape.second; ++i) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < grid_shape.first; ++j) {
        auto size = patch_side * patch_side * depth;
        auto map =
            Eigen::Map<Matrix>(patches.data() + batch_id * size, size);
        // Eigen::Matrix4f m = map;
        Matrix m = map;

        cv::Mat p;
        cv::eigen2cv(m, p);
        cv::imshow("p", p);
        cv::waitKey();
        /*
        ml(cv::Rect(i * patch_side, j * patch_side, patch_side,
                    patch_side)) =
            cv::Mat(cv::Size(patch_side, patch_side), CV_32F, patches.slice
                    patches.data() + (i + j) * patch_side * patch_side);
                    */

        std::cout << "i,j" << i << "," << j << "\n";
        batch_id++;
    }
}
```

So, how can I get a Matrix from a Eigen::Tensor (or tf::Tensor) that I'll be able to use into `cv::eigen2cv`?

Comment: "a batch of N patches, MxMxD" -> did you mean "NxMxD", or each patch is MxM, with depth D, and the output tensor is then "NxMxMxD"? Also can you indicate which line is giving you the compilation error?

Comment: Setting  `auto patches = outputs[0].flat<float>();` and running the code above, the error (YOU_TRIED_CALLING_A_VECTOR_METHOD_ON_A_MATRIX) is at the line  `Eigen::Map<Matrix>(patches.data() + batch_id * size, size)`.

A batch of N patches: a tensor with shape (N, M, M, D)

Comment: Ah, right, seems that you are not giving the right parameters to `Map`, you have indicated the data source but then you need to give the number of rows and columns (see the post you linked). However, I think this would only give you only the first channel for each patch - I'm not sure there is any way to make a multi-channel `cv::Mat` from `Eigen::Matrix`es in one shot...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about the rows/columns parameters. It solved my issue in this particular case, because  D = 1. However, I let the question opened here because a more general solution that can handle D > 1 will be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking a bit around [the documenation of OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a), and considering TensorFlow tensors are always row-major, you should be able to just do something like:

```
const auto patch_side = 256;
int batch_id = 0;
for (auto i = 0; i < grid_shape.second; ++i) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < grid_shape.first; ++j) {
        auto size = patch_side * patch_side * depth;
        cv::Mat p(patch_side, patch_side, CV_32FC(depth), patches.data() + batch_id * size);
        cv::imshow("p", p);
        cv::waitKey();
        /*
        ml(cv::Rect(i * patch_side, j * patch_side, patch_side,
                    patch_side)) =
            cv::Mat(cv::Size(patch_side, patch_side), CV_32F, patches.slice
                    patches.data() + (i + j) * patch_side * patch_side);
                    */

        std::cout << "i,j" << i << "," << j << "\n";
        batch_id++;
    }
}
```

Note this does *not* copy the tensor data but rather creates a `cv::Mat` that points to it.

Comment: This is a way better solution than using Eigen::Map in my case, since I need speed and low memory usage thus using pointers and not copying values is perfect for me. Thank you